# Unity: How could I change the text of a button using the inspector?

Tags: unity-game-engine, button, 3d

I am trying to make a title screen for my game and I cannot figure out how to change the text of a button using the Inspector.

Any ways I could do this?

Answer (score 2):

Oops. I just realized the text is a child of the button. Never mind, don't answer!

Answer (score 0):

Aight mate!

It is a common mistake... it is fine.
I'd advise you to use TextMesh Pro.

It is a better way and a way more customizable option.
It has crispier text and looks cleaner.

If you need any help, you can ask me out.